# Allow nulls in the API Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

If employeeId is not available, how do I enable web api to accept null as the parameter. I have already made integer nullable in api request also applied **?** in the route.

1. /api/Employee/{employeeId}/Subscriber/80
2. **/api/Employee/null/Subscriber/80**

For some reason I can not move the nullable parameter to the end right now.

Comment: Have you assigned the default value for the `employeeID`

Comment: Beacause I have tried with your URL is not working for optional parameter

Comment: But in my case `[Route("v1/ticketreport/total/{id?}")]` is working fine without an issue and in method `string id=null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have situation wherein certain parameters can be null, I think it would make more sense to create alternate routes for them.

So this: `/api/Employee/null/Subscriber/80`, would become something like this: `/api/Employee/Subscriber/80`.

The above logic assumes that you can get to a subscriber without an employee Id. This should result into cleaner, more defined flows.